# Firefox : Disabling "Command"+Digit shortcut

Tags: keyboard, firefox

I found out, that Firefox reacts on the key combination *command* + *n*, where *n* is a digit, to switch to the n-th open tab.

I wonder whether this can be turned off for Firefox at least. I found the same annoying behaviour in iTerm2, but this program let's me turn off these shortcuts.